# FB.api('/me/photos', function(result) {} doesn't return anything in Safari

Tags: facebook, safari

```
$('#login').live('click',function(e){
                        $(this).hide();
                        login();        
                    });

                    // login
                    function login(){
                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse != 'undefined' && response.authResponse != null) {
                                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                                    // remember user ID
                                    uID = response.authResponse.userID;
                                    if(uID) getMostTagged();
                                });                                                                                                                 
                            } else { alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.'); }
                        },{scope: 'user_photos,user_videos,user_photo_video_tags'});
                    }

                    // get friend with most pic tags
                    function getMostTagged(){   
                        FB.api('/me/photos', {fields: 'tags'}, function(result) {
   console.log(result);                         
}
```

The problem is that there is nothing in the result in Safari whereas its works fine in Firefox and Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I logged with wrong Facebook ID and thats why I couldn't get anything.